# Get a while in a while SQL

Tags: sql-server, while-loop

I'd like to be able to use a while in a while in SQL, so this is my query:

```
DECLARE  My_Cursor CURSOR LOCAL FOR 
    SELECT  
        TimeByDay, Matricule, ResourceNTAccount, CommandNumber,
        Post, Actuals, ResourceEmailAddress 
    FROM 
        #Results 
    WHERE 
        Matricule IS NOT NULL 
    ORDER BY 
        TimeByDay, Matricule 

OPEN My_Cursor 

FETCH NEXT FROM My_Cursor INTO @TimeByDay, @Matricule, @ResourceNTAccount, @CommandNumber, @Post, @Actuals, @ResourceEmailAddress

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #POTemp

    SELECT *
    INTO #POTemp
    FROM #Commands 
    WHERE ResourceWorkEmail = @ResourceEmailAddress 
      AND @TimeByDay BETWEEN ValidFrom AND ValidTo

    DECLARE My_Cursor1 CURSOR LOCAL FOR 
         SELECT  
             RemainingHours, CommandNumber, Post, ResourceWorkEmail, 
             ValidFrom, ValidTo, COObject, Actuals 
         FROM 
             #POTemp 
         WHERE 
             @Actuals > 0 
         ORDER BY 
             ValidFrom   

         OPEN My_Cursor1 

         FETCH NEXT FROM My_Cursor1 INTO @RemainingHours, @CommandNumberPO, @PostPO, @ResourceWorkEmail, @ValidFrom, @ValidTo, @COObject, @ActualsPO

         WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
         BEGIN
             IF @RemainingHours - @Actuals > 0
                 UPDATE #Commands 
                 SET [Actuals] = @Actuals;
                 --SET @Actuals=0;
             ELSE
                 UPDATE #ApprovedLines
                 SET [Actuals] = @Actuals

             UPDATE #Commands
             SET [ACTUALS] = @Actuals - @RemainingHours

             FETCH NEXT FROM My_Cursor1 INTO @RemainingHours, @CommandNumberPO, @PostPO, @ResourceWorkEmail, @ValidFrom, @ValidTo, @COObject, @ActualsPO
        CLOSE My_Cursor1
        DEALLOCATE My_Cursor1
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM My_Cursor INTO @TimeByDay, @Matricule, @ResourceNTAccount, @CommandNumber, @Post, @Actuals, @ResourceEmailAddress
    CLOSE My_Cursor
    DEALLOCATE My_Cursor
END
```

But when I execute my query I have the following error messages:

> A cursor with the name 'My_Cursor1' already exists.
>
> Msg 16905, Level 16, State 1, Line 179
>   The cursor is already open.
>
> Msg 16916, Level 16, State 1, Line 198
>   A cursor with the name 'My_Cursor' does not exist.
>
> Msg 16916, Level 16, State 1, Line 199
>   A cursor with the name 'My_Cursor' does not exist.
>
> Msg 16916, Level 16, State 1, Line 200
>   A cursor with the name 'My_Cursor' does not exist.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Yes!!! What you are doing wrong is using loops here in the first place. Nested cursors for nothing more than updating data is completely the wrong way to go about this. You need to do this set based instead.

Comment: Now that your code is indented a little bit, you can probably see what is wrong.

Comment: *Don't* use cursors. SQL is a set-based language. Cursors are needed only in *very rare cases* and perform at least N times slower than any query affecting N rows. They are also far more difficult to write than a proper query

Comment: While the formatting should shed some light on the logical issue here the best way to fix this is to get this out of RBAR (row by agonizing row) logic. This looks like the entire nested cursor structure could be replaced with a single update statement using some aggregation.

Comment: If you want to update some rows based on a query write an `UPDATE ... FROM ...WHERE` query

Comment: I'm not using the cursor because I want
It's just because I have no other choice :/
It's just a part of my code
First I wanted to do it with windows function but on q special case, it's not working; this is why I have to do it with 2 loops